# ActiveStorage AnalyzeJob not running in test environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

When attachments are created in my Rails 5.2 test environment, an `AnalyzeJob` is not being created. I thought it may be because my service was set to `Disk`, but even when I set it to `S3`, I don't see those jobs being created. Am I missing something?

Comment: what do your "config/storage.yml" and the "config/environments/test.rb" look like? As well as the relevant code where you expect the analyze job to be created and the type of file to be analyzed

Comment: @engineersmnky the storage.yml is used in development just fine. I'm not sure what could change behavior in the environment file?